# php echo() does not show output in html format when using data from handlebars

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, handlebars.js

when i pass an hardcoded html string to php echo() it gets parsed to html format, but when the data from handlebars is passed it doesn't work.

```
  <li style="width:33%;padding:15px">Info : <?php echo"{{{envinfo}}}"?></li>





<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#yehhua").click(function(){
          alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
        });
        $(function() {
            $('#users').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '{!! route('jobapps') !!}',
                buttons: [
                    'excel', 'pdf'
                ],
                columns: [
                    { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
                    {
                        "className":'details-control',
                        "orderable":false,
                        "ordeing":false,
                        "searchable":false,
                        "data":null,
                        "defaultContent":''
                    },

                    { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
                    { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
                    { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at' },
                    { data: 'phone', name: 'phone' },
                    { data: 'location', name: 'location' },
                    { data: 'envinfo', name: 'envinfo' }
                ]
            });

        });


            $('#users').on('click','td.details-control' ,function () {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = table.row(tr);
                if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                 }
                else {
                        row.child( template(row.data()) ).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }
            });


      var template = Handlebars.compile($('#details-template').html());


    </script>
```

tried many ways to echo the string, even tried storing it in a variable first thn using that variable in echo()

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgiwd.png)

Comment: PHP is server side language and handlebar is javascript framework that works on client side. so `echo` will not get the variable from handlebars.

Comment: @SaineshMamgain ok 

Comment: use `echo "{{{"."envinfo"."}}}"`. But this will only print the handlebars placeholder in html, WILL NOT evaluate it as PHP is on server-side while handlebars is run on client-side

Answer (score 0):

handlebar is a javascript framework, and it is clearly seen that that handlebar data is in json format. you need to parse it before using with php